# Google Map API, Geocoder.GetLocations always returns "Browser Incompatible"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am using JavaScript base google map API, when ever I try to use geocoder.getlocations it returns "Browser Incompatibility" exception and unloads the map. Please take a look at my code and let me know what is wrong with it.

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GNavLabelControl());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
  }
}

function showAddress(address) {
var zipcodex = 0;
if(geocoder)
{
    geocoder.getLocations(address, getzip); 

function getzip (response) 
    {
    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
        {
        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first address");
        }
    else
        {
        if(response.Placemark[0].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.
        Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber)
            {
            zipcodex = response.Placemark[0].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.
            Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber;
            } 

        }

    }
}

  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.getLatLng(
      address,
      function(point) {
        if (!point) {
          alert(address + " not found");
        } else {
          map.setCenter(point, 13);
          var marker = new GMarker(point);
          map.addOverlay(marker);
    if(zipcode)
    {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml('Zipcode:'+zipcodex);
    }
    else
    {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
    }
        }
      }
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using version 3 of the Google Maps API, unless there is a reason you have to stick with version 2. Try the example given here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingRequests

Comment: i guess this does not address my problem